# Not able to import matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook while it looks actually installed correctly in the correct Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After looking at many answers to same problem in stackoverflow, I must recognize that I am facing a strange situation.
I am on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.
**In my jupyter notebook**, I get the following configuration:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) 
[GCC 7.3.0]

sys.path
['/home/hector/_NOTEBOOKS',
 '',
 '/home/hector/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python37.zip',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/hector/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/hector/snap/jupyter/6/.ipython']
```

But when I try to import matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0484cd13f94d> in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Now when I open a **terminal console and actually launch python3.7**

```
hector@lenovo2:/snap/jupyter/6/bin$ ./python3.7
>>> import matplotlib
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python37.zip', '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7', '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/hector/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

>>> matplotlib.__path__
['/home/hector/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib']
```

All looks like matplotlib is correctly installed for python3.7 in the `/home/hector/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` directory.
In jupyter notebook, this is listed as the first entry in sys.path for jupyter's python version (3.7), and despite this configuration, and to my highest despair, jupyter notebook does not find matplotlib...

I appreciate all help and ideas to resolve this dilemma :-)

Thanks

Comment: When using python3 version of jupyter (`pip3 install jupyter`), matplotlib has to be installed using pip3: `pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: Thanks - I'm now at office I will have a look on my linux box when back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to proceed as per the comment on my question and recommending to install jupyter and all the rest with pip3.

I had a doubt about my overall installation because there was nothing available as 'pip3' on my system.

In fact the issue was related to the fact that I initially installed jupyter notebook with the apt package provided with Ubunutu, and I actually **should not have**.

This Ubuntu apt package delivers a 'snap' installation wich is very bounded and separated from other python instances on the computer. It 'messes up' python, in such a way that one **really** gets situation like described in my question.

My first step has been to **remove apt installation of jupyter**:

```
> sudo apt remove jupyter-notebook
> sudo apt remove jupyter
> sudo apt autoremove
```

My second step has been to **install pip3 for my current python3 installation**:

```
> sudo apt install python3-pip
```

My third step has been to **install notebook with pip3** (instead of using Ubuntu's apt package) :

```
> pip3 install jupyter
```

Finally, I could **install a matplotlib that can be imported from within the jupyter notebook, using pip3** (note, as a prerequisite a few dependencies had to be installed):

```
#Prerequisite dependencies
> sudo apt install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev

# THE HAPPY END FINALLY COMES WITH:

> pip3 install matplotlib

#(claps and happiness here)
```

Cheers